# Invoke WCF Method asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, asynchronous

I have the following problem:

My WCF-Method looks like this

```
public TransferResult<bool> ExecuteMyMethod(string jobName, 
                                   Collection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters)
{
    do something;
}
```

The corresponding contract:

```
[OperationContract]
TransferResult<bool> ExecuteMyMethod(string jobName, 
                                  Collection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters);
```

Now in our project there exists a proxy wrapper with which you can invoke methods asynchronously and which I must use:

```
 public void InvokeAsync<TArg1, TArg2, TResult>(
    Expression<Func<IMyServiceClient, Func<TArg1, TArg2, AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult>>> beginMethod, 
    Expression<Func<IMyServiceClient, Func<IAsyncResult, TransferResult<TResult>>>> endMethod, 
    TArg1 arg1, 
    TArg2 arg2, 
    Action<Task<TransferResult<TResult>>> continuationAction)
{
    do something;
}
```

When I try to invoke my method like this:

```
this.wrapper.InvokeAsync<string, Collection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>, bool>(
                svc => svc.BeginExecuteMyMethod,
                svc => svc.EndExecuteMyMethod,
                "jobname",
                parameters,
                this.ContinuationAction);
```

The VS keeps telling me:

> Expected a method with 'IAsyncResult BeginExecuteMyMethod(string,
>        Collection>, AsyncCallback, object)'
>        signature

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
The parameters parameter is of type Collection>
I am very new to WCF and don't really know what the problem is :(

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

I verified that the attribute `[OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern=true)]` is set on the `BeginExecuteMyMethod` method in the service reference

**Edit2**
This is what the body of the IMyServiceClient looks like

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IMyService/ExecuteMyMethod", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IMyService/ExecuteMyMethod")]
TransferResult<bool> ExecuteMyMethod(string jobName, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<MyService.KeyValuePairOfstringstring> parameters);

[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern=true, Action="http://tempuri.org/IMyService/ExecuteMyMethod", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IMyService/ExecuteMyMethod")]
System.IAsyncResult BeginExecuteMyMethod(string jobName, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<MyService.KeyValuePairOfstringstring> parameters, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);
TransferResult<bool> EndExecuteMyMethod(System.IAsyncResult result);
```

Comment: You need to provide [asynchronous version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177(v=vs.110).aspx) of your `ExecuteMyMethod` method.

Comment: hey michael thanks for your comment. I just verified in the reference that this attribute is set: `[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern=true, Action=".....")]` the service reference is set to "allow generation of asynchronous operations -> Generate asynchronous operations" which added the attribute automatically

Comment: Could you please post body of your `IMyServiceClient` ?

Comment: Sure, I edited the original post with the body of the IMyServiceClient

Comment: Please don't rename your classes to post code examples. You are likely introducing bugs (or else your interface really does not have a `BeginExecuteMyMethod` and that is your real problem)

Comment: Sadly I'm obliged to change names etc. :( But there is a BeginExecuteMyMethod in the interface? `[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern=true, Action="http://tempuri.org/IMyService/ExecuteMyMethod", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IMyService/ExecuteMyMethod")]
System.IAsyncResult BeginExecuteMyMethod(string jobName, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<MyService.KeyValuePairOfstringstring> parameters, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);` or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the **BeginExecuteMethod**, parameters is type of **Collection<KeyValuePairOfstringstring>**, but if you look at your wrapper, you're calling InvokeAsync with different type **Collection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>**

BeginExecute method

```
IAsyncResult BeginExecuteMyMethod(string jobName, Collection<KeyValuePairOfstringstring> parameters, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);
```

InvokeAsync call

```
this.wrapper.InvokeAsync<string, Collection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>, bool>(
            svc => svc.BeginExecuteMyMethod,
            svc => svc.EndExecuteMyMethod,
            "jobname",
            parameters,
            this.ContinuationAction);
```